# Cordova ios [cordova-plugin-openwith-ios plugin] app myHandler function is not executing

Tags: cordova

I have a cordova IOS application. In which user can share text data from other apps. I used cordova-plugin-openwith-ios plugin to get the app in share option. App is displaying in share option and app is opening but it is not showing the shared data. Its not calling the myHandler function. App is working on emulator but not in real device. Tested on Iphone SE and Iphone 6 (iOS 11 updated).

**What I have tried:**

I have tried below plugins but it worked for only images not for text.

https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-openwith

So is any other way to do it, or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

When you install you have to run the following command to get the MIME type support for images/text/pdf this is the one.

cordova plugin add cc.fovea.cordova.openwith --variable ANDROID_MIME_TYPE="text/* , application/pdf, image/*"

Answer (score 0):

For IOS it is required to set this variable

```
 --variable IOS_UNIFORM_TYPE_IDENTIFIER=public.image
```

possible values are indicated at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1